# Build Record Root Directory in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I am working on jenkins.All my build information is stored in build record root directory.But I am having 3 users with their individual jobs and all the build information is been written into my Build Record Root Directory.Is It possible to have a seperate Build Record Root Directory for individual users so that the user can see only their job build information.

Answer (score 0):

The following [post](http://ingorichter.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html) describes step by step how to change Jenkins Workspaces and Build Directory Locations.